# Bootstrap: limit affix height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have it like this:

```
<div id="treeview" class="container col-md-3">
    <div id="tree" data-spy="affix"></div>
</div>
```

The `#tree` div is filled with [bootstrap-treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview). The generated tree has unpredictable height, so I want it to have some reasonable fixed height and a scrollbar (I try to do it with mu custom #treeview or #tree styles). Preferably, the width should be limited too in the same way. But when I put `data-spy="affix"` it all like gets ignored.

Comment: give `min-height` and `overflow-y:scroll` to ID `#tree`.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Didn't work at all (and I don't see why should it).

Comment: I hope you understand why I am using `min-height` here. sometime `min-height` work with when define the `height` value as well.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Worked. But why wasn't only to set `height` enough? Would you post it as answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min-height` is usually used to ensure that an element has at least a minimum height even if no content is present; it’s also commonly used in conjunction with `max-height` to produce a height range for the element concerned.

so in your case you've to give a `min-height` and `overflow-y:scroll` to ID `#treeview`.

READ More on **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)**